# is there "main" gyp file?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, gyp

There are so many gyp & gypi files in chromium source code.  Which one is sort of "main" gyp that hold most crucial information?  Is there any documentation that I can refer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$CHROME_SRC/build/all.gyp` and `$CHROME_SRC/build/common.gypi`